# Android: GUID Primary key

Tags: android, sqlite, primary-key, android-cursor

I know if I don't use a field named _id as my primary key in Android, that certain things like the CursorAdapter won't work, but does the _id column need to be an autoincrement int?

Could I use a Guid as the key, as long as it's called _id, and have the CursorAdapter still work?

Answer (score 3):

The yellow box in the [storage guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) says:

> Android does not impose any
> limitations beyond the standard SQLite
> concepts. We do recommend including an
> autoincrement value key field that can
> be used as a unique ID to quickly find
> a record. This is not required for
> private data, but if you implement a
> content provider, you must include a
> unique ID using the BaseColumns._ID
> constant.

Now when you click on the [BaseColumns](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/BaseColumns.html#_ID) class you will see

> `public static final String _ID`
>
> The unique ID for a row.
>
> Type: INTEGER (long)
>
> Constant Value: "_id"

So I guess, a GUID will not work.

Comment: That's too bad.  :(  I would have liked to use the same UUID values between remote and local synchronized data.

Comment: @JRLawhorne: Nothing prevents you from storing the UUID as an additional field (not named `_ID`). A table can have more than one unique key.